# Etext Oracle : How to get the count of rows on the first line of output instead of last

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a Headcount report where I have to present a trailer record showing the count of the rows present in my main record in a separate file.
So I am simply creating an empty record with no attributes for the main Record and then running a count for the rows present in that record. Now the problem is my count line is coming all rows are executed for the main record which are nothing but just empty blank lines due to which my count line is coming at the bottom I want a way to write the Count Line in the first line instead of the last.

[As you can see in the image after 4 blank lines we are having the 5th line as the count line showing the count as 4 how to write this line on the first line??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHBxk.png)

I am also adding screenshots of my etext template and the xml from which this data is being retreived
[etext template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEaeB.png)
[xml file with sensitive data blacked out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gduQJ.png)

Comment: People will be more amenable to helping if you provide same create table statements along with data and your expected output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Beefstu I have added the etext template I used and the xml from which the data is being derived so can you look at it and see if you can help out

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Please provide create table script(s), sample data (no images), a minimal reproducible CASE, your attempt and the expected outcome as very few people here are going to type in your data and table definitions when it could be cut and pasted